# Get Json results from remote source with autocomplete inside a contenteditable div

Tags: jquery, datasource, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, getjson

Using jQuery UI Autocomplete and targeting a contenteditable, with multiple "tags" starting with the "@" character, I have an example of everything I'm trying to do but one thing is missing. I need to pull a remote source for the data.

Below you will see the "tags" array and that array referenced halfway down at the end of the "source" option. I have tried various jQuery.ajax and jQuery.getJson methods to return the data but can't seem to do it. The jQuery UI examples all fail me because they remove certain features that are already working. Since "this.value" doesn't work for contenteditable DIVs (only for form fields) and a simple getJson runs after the code has executed, I'm certain there's a way but I am at a loss.

If someone could use this data source to help me get the results, it woudl be really great.
http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php

I tried many variations of the jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ demos and there were too many rising issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/T45rQ/7/

```
var tags = [
    "example.com"
    ,"akamai.com"
    ,"2charts.com"
    ,"gmail.com"
    ,"jquery.com"
    ,"yahoo.com"
    ,"ymail.com"
    ,"hotmail.com"
];
var startTyping = "Start Typing";


function placeCaretAtEnd(el) {
    el.focus();
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined"
            && typeof document.createRange != "undefined") {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(el);
        range.collapse(false);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
    } else if (typeof document.body.createTextRange != "undefined") {
        var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        textRange.moveToElementText(el);
        textRange.collapse(false);
        textRange.select();
    }
}
function split( val ) {
    return val.split( /@/ );
}
function extractLast( term ) {
    return split( term ).pop();
}

$("#MyText")
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term,
                results = [];
            if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                term = extractLast(request.term);
                if (term.length > 0) {
                    results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, term);
                } else {
                    results = [startTyping];
                }
            }
            response(results);
        },
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value !== startTyping) {
                var value = $(this).html();
                var terms = split(value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                $(this).html(terms.join("@"));
                placeCaretAtEnd(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
        if (item.label != startTyping) {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a><div>" + item.label + "</div></div></a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        } else {
            return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
        }
    }
;
```

Comment: The problem is that your datasource has to have `value` and `label` elements as part of the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks @DevlshOne. I may have over complicated my question. The issue is trying to pull in remote data, say from a data source like [link](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php)

Comment: Well, as long as you return the data from the `search.php` script with a valid `value` and `label` element in the JSON object, you should be ok. Are your tags in a database?

Comment: That's the thing, I can't seem to figure out how to call the data from within the "source" option. When I try to use the jQuery example to get the data, how can I pass that along to replace the "tags" array a few lines below:'          $.getJSON( "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
          }, response );'

Comment: If you're using an external source, you won't have a `tags` array, you'll have whatever the response is from the source script `search.php`.

Comment: Read this again very carefully. Look at the sample `search.php` script I typed up. That's about as much help as I can give you, sorry.
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: Thanks @DevlshOne for the code block, I'm still not clear how I will get the returned data from search.php into the autocomplete "search" option so that I can run the $.ui.autocomplete.filter on it and get the "results".

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/T45rQ/131/)**

A little re-write on your `.autocomplete()` options:

```
$("#MyText")
    .bind("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
    .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        search: function (request, response) {
            var term = request.term,
                results = [];
            if (term.indexOf("@") >= 0) {
                term = extractLast(request.term);
                if (term.length > 0) {
                    results = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(tags, term);
                } else {
                    results = [startTyping];
                }
            }
            response(results);
        },
        source: 'search.php',
        focus: function () {
            return false;
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item.value !== startTyping) {
                var value = $(this).html();
                var terms = split(value);
                terms.pop();
                terms.push(ui.item.value);
                $(this).html(terms.join("@"));
                placeCaretAtEnd(this);
            }
            return false;
        }
    })
```

Let's say you have a list of all of these domain names stored in a database. Your `search.php` file would look something like this:

```
<?
$return_data = [];
$term = $_REQUEST[term];
$q = "SELECT domain_name AS value, domain_name AS label FROM domain_table WHERE domain_name LIKE '" . $term . "%'";
$r = $mysqli_db->query($q);
while ($row = $r->fetch_assoc()) {
    array_push($return_data,$row);
}
$r->free();
echo json_encode($return_data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
?>
```